# Can I go to Netherlands for thesis(6 months) on student visa which I got in Germany?

Tags: germany, student-visa, netherlands, schengen, study

I am a non-Eu Master student in Germany. For this, I got a student visa (Schengen -type D).  I have got an offer from a university in the Netherlands for the thesis. My question is on this visa can I go for 6months in the Netherlands. Also, the university is going to offer me some salary. will that violate some laws?
I have found a [link](https://www.educations.com/study-guides/europe/study-in-netherlands/student-visa-5837) which says I can go to the Netherlands and can register in the city with the Job/Internship offer for stays longer than 3 months on the Netherlands. Wanted to confirm if this info in authentic

Comment: Refer to the international department of your university, or the administrative staff of the host lab in the Netherlands. You probably need a dutch visa as a worker or a scientist (scientist would be the case in France for example).

Comment: @la femme cosmique Thanks for your inputs. I tried contacting local"foreigners Authority" in Germany. They say that we can give you clearance for moving out but cannot comment about visa requirements in the Netherlands. rather they asked me to check with Netherlands consulate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> on this visa can I go for 6months in the Netherlands?

No.  National visas, also known as type-D or long-stay visas, are governed by national law.  They do not allow you to spend more than 90 days in any 180-day period in other Schengen countries.  To stay in the Netherlands for six months, you need a visa or residence permit issued by the Netherlands.

> Also, the university is going to offer me some salary. will that violate some laws?

Not if you have permission from the Netherlands to work.  This might take the form of an appropriate visa, or it might be a separate work authorization.

> I have found a link which says I can go to the Netherlands and can register in the city with the Job/Internship offer for stays longer than 3 months on the Netherlands.

The site seems legitimate, but unofficial, and it is somewhat out of date with respect to Bulgarian and Romanian citizens.  I would look for a better source of advice such as https://www.studyinholland.nl/ (which is the source of the information on the page you found).  Their relevant page is [Visas and permits](https://www.studyinholland.nl/prepare/visas-and-permits).

Comment: Thanks for response! Finally I found the link whuch caters my need. [link](https://www.studyinholland.nl/study/internship/internship-as-part-of-a-programme-abroad)

Comment: @NikhilGaikwad please upvote questions and answers that you find helpful, and consider [accepting](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) this answer if you find it appropriate.

Comment: Yup! I have accepted the answer, but I don't have enough credits(reputations) to upvote as I am a new user.

Comment: @NikhilGaikwad weird.  I would have thought that you'd be able to vote on answers to your own question.